# pandas group by and find first non null value for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pyspark, window

I have pandas DF as below ,

```
id  age   gender  country  sales_year
1   None   M       India    2016
2   23     F       India    2016
1   20     M       India    2015
2   25     F       India    2015
3   30     M       India    2019
4   36     None    India    2019
```

I want to group by on id, take the latest 1 row as per sales_date with all non null element.

output expected,

```
id  age   gender  country  sales_year
1   20     M       India    2016
2   23     F       India    2016
3   30     M       India    2019
4   36     None    India    2019
```

In pyspark,

```
df = df.withColumn('age', f.first('age', True).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(df.sales_year.desc())))
```

But i need same solution in pandas .

***EDIT*** :: 
This can the case with all the columns. Not just age. I need it to pick up latest non null data(id exist) for all the ids.

Comment: your output still contains `None` values, unless I am missing something

Comment: if none of the row have any valid data then **None** is fine.. But if available it should detect the way in the example for id 1, age got replaced from second highest year data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
   id   age gender country  sales_year
0   1  20.0      M   India        2016
1   2  23.0      F   India        2016
2   3  30.0      M   India        2019
3   4  36.0    NaN   India        2019
```

If column `sales_year` is not sorted:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('sales_year', ascending=False).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df2)
   id   age gender country  sales_year
0   1  20.0      M   India        2016
1   2  23.0      F   India        2016
2   3  30.0      M   India        2019
3   4  36.0    NaN   India        2019
```

Comment: How this is sorting the data as per **sales_year** ? I need latest year's row as first.

Comment: is there any way, i can do this for all the columns ?  I have 20 + columns like this. i wish to do it in one go for all of them.. as sorting remains on same column 'sales_year' and group by also remain same on 'id' column.

Comment: @j' - It seems you want original solution with sorting before? Because `first` return first non `None` or not `NaN`s value per all columns, so it is reson because `2016` in first row.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df.replace('None',np.NaN).groupby('id').first())
```

- first replace the 'None' with NaN
- next use groupby() to group by 'id'
- next filter out the first row using first()

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df.dropna(subset=['gender']).sort_values('sales_year', ascending=False).groupby('id')['age'].first()
```

**Output**

```
id
1    20
2    23
3    30
4    36
Name: age, dtype: object
```

Remove the `['age']` to get full rows -

```
df.dropna().sort_values('sales_year', ascending=False).groupby('id').first()
```

**Output**

```
   age gender country  sales_year
id                               
1   20      M   India        2015
2   23      F   India        2016
3   30      M   India        2019
4   36   None   India        2019
```

You can put the `id` back as a column with `reset_index()` -

```
df.dropna().sort_values('sales_year', ascending=False).groupby('id').first().reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   id age gender country  sales_year
0   1  20      M   India        2015
1   2  23      F   India        2016
2   3  30      M   India        2019
3   4  36   None   India        2019
```

Comment: id a column here and not index. Can't change it

Comment: Added `reset_index()` @j'

Comment: Also, df.dropna() will remove all the rows havinf atleast 1 None value.. I don't want that.. i have 20 more columns in this DF. Given solution is not working

Comment: You can specify column subset in `dropna()` with `subset` parameter. Updated ans pls check