# Finding the first appearence of a row with respect to a feature in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The title may not be super clear. What I want to do is the following.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["1", "2", "3", "1", "4", "5", "2", "6", "3", "1", "4"],
        "value": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "D", "A"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
)
```

Using this data frame I'd like to create a new data frame with the rows those appear for the first time the with respect to the column "id". So, it would mean the rows with the indices: 0,1,2,4,5 and 7.

I hope the problem is expressed clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Similar: [pandas group by and find first non null value for all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59048308/15497888)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you want to retain the indices as you mention

You can do a reverse of [`series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) on `id` by using a `~` and then a boolean masking:

```
df[~df['id'].duplicated()]
```

---

```
  id value
0  1     A
1  2     A
2  3     B
4  4     B
5  5     C
7  6     A
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
print(df.groupby("id", as_index=False).first())
```

Prints:

```
  id value
0  1     A
1  2     A
2  3     B
3  4     B
4  5     C
5  6     A
```