# How to combine rows with same id number using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big csv file and I would like to combine rows with the same id#.
For instance, this is what my csv shows right now.
[image]

and I would like it to be like this:

[image]

how can I do this using pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas group by and find first non null value for all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048308/pandas-group-by-and-find-first-non-null-value-for-all-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('id').agg({'name':'last', 
                           'type':'last', 
                           'date':'last' }).reset_index()
```

this way you can have customized function in handling each columns.
(By changing the function from 'last' to your function)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv with [pd.read_csv() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then use the [GroupBy.last() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) to aggregate rows with the same id.

something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
df1 = df.groupby('id').last()
```

you should also decide an aggregation function instead of using "the last" row value.